# How to make ng-repeat statement in angular JS run for a limited number of times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a table which is being populated like this :

```html
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Score</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in data.items">
            <td><a href="{{ x.get }}">{{ x.id }}</td>
            <td>
                <p><b>{{ x.name[0] }}</b></p>
                <p><u>Brand</u>: {{ x.Brand }}; <u>Category URL</u>: {{ x.mlnURL }};<u>Price</u>: Rs {{x.Price}} </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p><a href="{{x.explain}}"><b>{{ x.score }}</b></a></p>
                Classifier Score: {{ x.cscore }} <br>
                Document Score: {{ x.sscore }} </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Now in this line

```html
<tr ng-repeat="x in data.items">
```

instead of running foe all the x in data.items , i want to run it a limited number of times according to how the user wants . I have this number input from the user and stored in a variable . How can i achieve this .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:
`<tr ng-repeat="x in data.items | limitTo: 2">`

It will repeat 2 times with this code. You can change the 2 to a var on your scope.

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize the filter [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo), like the example below:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCont', function($scope) {
    var theItems = [{
      name: 'walkman',
      Brand: 'sony',
      Price: 20,
      explain: 'an AM/FM cassette player',
      score: 89,
      mlnURL: 'http://sony.com'
    }, {
      name: 'discman',
      Brand: 'sony',
      Price: 30,
      explain: 'a CD player',
      score: 83,
      mlnURL: 'http://sony.com'
    }, {
      name: ['ipod'],
      Brand: 'Apple',
      Price: 200,
      explain: 'an MP3 player',
      score: 89,
      mlnURL: 'http://apple.com'
    },
    {
      name: ['Flash Player'],
      Brand: 'SanDisk',
      Price: 40,
      explain: 'an MP3 player',
      score: 79,
      mlnURL: 'http://sandisk.com'
    }];
    $scope.data = {items: theItems};
  $scope.limit = 2;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCont">
  # of items to show <input type="number" ng-model="limit"/>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Details</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data.items | limitTo: limit">
      <td><a href="{{ x.get }}">{{ x.id }}</td>
            <td>
                <p><b>{{ x.name[0] }}</b></p>
                <p><u>Brand</u>: {{ x.Brand }}; <u>Category URL</u>: {{ x.mlnURL }};<u>Price</u>: Rs {{x.Price}} </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p><a href="{{x.explain}}"><b>{{ x.score }}</b></a>
        </p>
        Classifier Score: {{ x.cscore }}
        <br>Document Score: {{ x.sscore }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily by using existing filter.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="numberOfRecord" />
```

Then you can use it in ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data.items | limitTo: numberOfRecord">
```

People usually use combo box to get the number of records per page and further you can use pagination if you want.

Hope your query resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, if you have the user input, is create a new array containing all the number of values you want.

In your controller you could do:

```
var toShow = data.items.slice(0, size);
```

And just use the toShow array in your template. Every time the size gets updated, you recalculate the toShow array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data.items | limitTo: 2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use limitTo filter in angularJs
Syntax is`{{item | limitTo : limit : begin}}`

```
<td ng-repeat="x in data.items | limitTo : userinput">
```

you can also specify where the list has to get started by using 'begin' as mentioned above